# How to send select option thats coming in as array from form in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a form with a select option, those options are brought in via an Array. When I post my form i get an error because I need the post response as json as going to api, and the value gets sent wrong:

currently going as:

```
category: {category: "Add"}
```

but needs to go as:

```
category: "Add"
```

my form field is:

```html
<label class="form-label" for="category">Category: <sub class="text-secondary">*</sub></label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4 col-sm-12">
                <select formControlName="category" class="form-select">
                  <option *ngFor="let state of category" [ngValue]="state">
                    {{ state.category }}
                  </option>
                </select>
```

**submit function in ts file.**

```ts
onSubmit() {
    if(this.serviceForm.invalid) {
       this.serviceForm.setErrors({ ...this.serviceForm.errors, 'required': true });
       return;
    }
    //this.loading = true;
    this.uploading = true;
    this.service.postRequest(this.serviceForm.value).subscribe((response: any) => {
      console.log(response);//On success response
      this.router.navigate(['/confirmation'],{queryParams: {value: response.result[0].display_value}});
    }, (errorResponse: any) => {
      console.log(errorResponse); //On unsuccessful response
    });
    }
  }
```

**service.ts**

```ts
  postRequest(payload) {
    //add return//
    return this.http.post(this.ApiUrl, payload, { headers: new HttpHeaders().set("Content-Type", "application/json") });
  }
```

Comment: replace `[ngValue]="state"` with `[value]="state.category"` in your html `<select>` tag. `ngValue` is not required

Comment: Submit as answer and I can accept, that worked fine.

Comment: But that has also taken out the default value?

Comment: What is the default value ? Do you have any already pre selected value?

Comment: `ngValue` is used to assign object as well instead of string.If you want to show a preselected value use `[(ngModel)]="selectedValue"` and set `this.selectedValue = <your default value>` in the ts file.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
<select  [(ngModel)]="model.selectedState">
                    <option selected value></option>
                    <option *ngFor="let p of project.favoriteProjects" [value]="state">  {{ state.category }}</option>
                  </select>
```